# ORACLE: Calculate storage requirement of table in terms of blocks on paper

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, database-tuning

I have to calculate storage requirements **in terms of blocks** for following table:

`Bill(billno number(7),billdate date,ccode varchar2(20),amount number(9,2))`

The table storage attributes are :

PCTFREE=20 , INITRANS=4 , PCTUSED=60 , BLOCKSIZE=8K , NUMBER OF ROWS=100000

I searched a lot on internet, referred many books but didn't got anything.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to figure out what is the typical value for `varchar2` column. The total size will depend on that. I created 2 tables from your `BILL` table. `BILLMAX` where `ccode` takes always 20 Char `('12345678901234567890')` and `BILLMIN` that has always `NULL` in `ccode`. 
The results are:

```
TABLE_NAME  NUM_ROWS    AVG_ROW_LEN BLOCKS
BILLMAX     3938        37          28
BILLMIN     3938        16          13

select table_name, num_rows, avg_row_len, blocks  from user_tables 
where table_name in ( 'BILLMIN', 'BILLMAX')
```

As you can see, the number of blocks depends on that. Use `exec dbms_stats.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('YourSchema','BILL')` to refresh values inside user_tables.

The other thing that you need to take into consideration is how big will be your extents. For example :

```
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
```

will generate first 16 extents with 8 blocks size. After that it will start to create extents with size of 1 MB (128 blocks).

So for `BILLMAX` it will generate 768 blocks and `BILLMIN` will take 384 blocks.
As you can see the difference is quite big.

For `BILLMAX` : 16 * 8 + 128 * 5 = 768

For `BILLMIN` : 16 * 8 + 128 * 2 = 384

Comment: I know how to get this info using `dbms_stats.GATHER_TABLE_STATS`. I want to calculate this theoretically.

Comment: The second part of my answer is for that. First you need to figure out how many rows fits in 1 block and then calculate number of blocks required. Then use STORAGE class to get idea how your EXTENTS look like and you have the result.